# Horizontal scrollview like shown in image

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

The screen should show the current image in the center and the next and previous images to its left and right in a smaller image size. [You can see the image here](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Xuj29uaLhEO44bePY93eqk6RvERKBeCTWO9RHPM2L18r-bBJ_1DJWsRTh6pzpEsT7k0=h900-rw) On swipe, the images should change and select as new item. It would be helpful if someone could point me to existing code similar to this. I have tried `Fancycoverflow`. it gives this kind of effect, but it skips items when I try to set particular item in center. I am not able to scroll and set the image in center easily.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://sourcey.com/android-horizontally-scrolling-pan-scan-and-zoom-image-gallery/) you can see something similar but not exactly. You can add round transformation, and bigger size that icon, which was clicked.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer i have solved my problem of selecting a single image at once using fancycoverflow by setting the spacing didn't get the exact view

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create a library for similar to your issue. You can custimize it for better suit. [Here](https://github.com/kgnkbyl/CustomViewPager) you can find the source code and a video that shows how it looks like.

See you.

Comment: thanks for your answer i have solved my problem of selecting a single image at once using fancycoverflow by setting the spacing didn't get the exact view